# img tag inserted dynamically with jquery not displaying image in IOS7

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, image, ipad

I have the fallowing situation :

```
   <script type="text/html" id='template'>

        <% _.each(items,function(item,key,list){ %>
            <div class="h100 w100p pline">

                  <div class="h100 w50p left">
                       <img class="thumbnail left" src="<%= item.img %>" />
                  </div>
            </div>

        <% }) %>

    </script>
```

The image is not display in Iphone 5 - IOS.7.03 and IPad IOS.7.02. I also tried this `$('.imag').css('background-image', 'url('+ '/style/zapp/cristal.png'+ ')');`  but i get the same result. I saw that IOS has some issues with displaying images but i would expect that with jQuery to be ok.

Any advice is highly appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be your issue but correct way to use a self closing tag as IMG is: `<img class="thumbnail left" src="<%= item.img %>">`

Comment: i managed to make it work with this solution : `$('.doi').html('<img src="style/zapp/cristal.png" />');' but still i can't find out what is the issues. the same weird behaviour happens with the [jRating](https://github.com/alpixel/jRating) jquery plugin - the star images are not loaded in IOS 7 - Iphone 5